# what SED -i does

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

Can anyone help explain what the command does on Ubuntu/Debian? Note there is no file called default. But there is one call default-ssl.conf.

```
sed -i '/AllowOverride None/c AllowOverride All' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

[Added]I searched the help page already but I am too new to understand the texts.
[Added 2]I conclude it is an ill command.

Comment: what answer do you expect that you could not find in the man page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about quoting the documentation

Comment: `man sed`? c'mon. We're happy to help. But we're not here so you can be lazy.

Comment: From `man sed`:  _-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)_ So the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` is edited with a string replacement in place, without making a backup or saving to a different file.

Comment: In case you're new to how command line utilities are documented in Unix-like environments, the "man pages" are the manuals for them.  Typing `man commandname` at the command line will bring up a documentation pager which lists options and basic usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't do anything if there is no file called `default`.

However, the -i flag means `edit in-place`, so it changes the file sed was run on.

`In place` means make changes to the file by actually changing the file, rather than leaving it intact and printing a new copy with the changes sed would make to stdout.

For more information on sed in general, I recommend reading the sed info page - `info sed`

Comment: Many thanks! in-place is what confuses me. What does it mean? And /c in the pattern means?